# Application has stopped working Issue

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

The idea is that you can horizontally scroll through the images, if you click on one it shows it enlarged above the button and if you press the button it would set the image as a wallpaper. But my application crashes on running:

here's the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IVDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button3_set"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSetBG"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:text="@string/button3_set" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="200"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Vimage1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="153dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button3_imgprev"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Vimage2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="153dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button3_imgprev"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Vimage3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="153dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button3_imgprev"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Vimage4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="153dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button3_imgprev"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_4" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Vimage5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="153dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button3_imgprev"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_5" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Vimage6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="153dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button3_imgprev"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_6" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Vimage7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="153dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button3_imgprev"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_7" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Vimage8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="153dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button3_imgprev"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_8" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Vimage9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="153dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button3_imgprev"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_9" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Vimage10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="153dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button3_imgprev"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_wallpaper" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the java:

```
package com.example.st;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Button3 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView display;
    int toPhone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.button_3);

        display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVDisplay);
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Vimage1);
        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Vimage2);
        ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Vimage3);
        ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Vimage4);
        ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Vimage5);
        ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Vimage6);
        ImageView image7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Vimage7);
        ImageView image8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Vimage8);
        ImageView image9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Vimage9);
        ImageView image10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Vimage10);

        Button setWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSetBG);

        toPhone = R.drawable.back_1;

        image1.setOnClickListener(this);
        image2.setOnClickListener(this);
        image3.setOnClickListener(this);
        image4.setOnClickListener(this);
        image5.setOnClickListener(this);
        image6.setOnClickListener(this);
        image7.setOnClickListener(this);
        image8.setOnClickListener(this);
        image9.setOnClickListener(this);
        image10.setOnClickListener(this);

        setWall.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.Vimage1:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_1);
            toPhone = R.drawable.back_1;
            break;

        case R.id.Vimage2:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_2);
            toPhone = R.drawable.back_2;
            break;
        case R.id.Vimage3:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_3);
            toPhone = R.drawable.back_3;
            break;
        case R.id.Vimage4:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_4);
            toPhone = R.drawable.back_4;
            break;
        case R.id.Vimage5:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_5);
            toPhone = R.drawable.back_5;
            break;
        case R.id.Vimage6:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_6);
            toPhone = R.drawable.back_6;
            break;
        case R.id.Vimage7:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_7);
            toPhone = R.drawable.back_7;
            break;
        case R.id.Vimage8:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_8);
            toPhone = R.drawable.back_8;
            break;
        case R.id.Vimage9:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_9);
            toPhone = R.drawable.back_9;
            break;
        case R.id.Vimage10:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_wallpaper);
            toPhone = R.drawable.back_wallpaper;
            break;

        case R.id.bSetBG:

            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

            Bitmap whatever = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources()
                    .openRawResource(toPhone));

            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(whatever);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(Button3.this, 
                           "Ooops, couldn't set the wallpaper", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Here are the errors that LogCat showed:

```
- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.st/com.example.st.Button3}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class <unknown>

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class <unknown>

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at com.example.st.Button3.onCreate(Button3.java:24)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   ... 11 more

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   ... 26 more

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:501)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:354)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)

- 07-24 00:53:44.524: E/AndroidRuntime(4663):   ... 29 more
```

Comment: When an application crashes, check the logcat to see why. It'll show you the runtime error and the line number at which the error occurred.

Comment: have you added the activity  in manifest file.

Comment: Just paste your logcat

Comment: And the `AndroidManifest` as well.

Comment: yeah the activity is added to the AndroidManifest file and i've pasted the errors shown in the LogCat above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you have a `OutOfMemory` error...

What size are your Bitmap Images?

Maybe you should try to add `android:largeHeap="true"` into your AndroidManifest file in the `application` section.

Comment: Yeah the images were quite large. I added **android:largeHeap="true"**, but it still didn't work, I then moved the images from **\res\drawable-hdpi**  to   **\res\drawable-xxhdpi**   and it works. Thanks